# Virtuemart get products from category without limit

Tags: joomla, virtuemart

I am trying to pull all articles from single VirtueMart category. I am having problem with pagination and default settings set in VirtueMart (max items per page).

I have this code below which works for limited number of articles (set in VM settings). This gives data for 40 articles. Is there a way to pass parameter of a page I want to load?
For example, if I have 400 articles, VM will show 10 pages in pagination. How can I pass pagination and load page number 2 for example?
I do not mind if have to load all 400 articles at once and implement my own pagination.

```
        include_once JPATH_ROOT . '/administrator/components/com_virtuemart/models/product.php';
        $model = new VirtueMartModelProduct();
        $items = $model->getProductsInCategory($this->input->get("catid"));

        foreach ($items as $key => $item) {

            $item = get_object_vars($item);
            $item['media'] = $mediaModel->getFiles("", "", $item['virtuemart_product_id']);
            
            $objekt = (object)[
                "mf_name" => $item['mf_name'],
                'product_name' => $item['product_name'],
                'prices' => [
                    'product_override_price' => $item['prices']['product_override_price'],
                    'product_price' => $item['prices']['product_price'],
                    'discountAmount' => $item['prices']['discountAmount'],
                ],
                'file_url' => $item['media'][0]->file_url,
                'virtuemart_category_id' => $item['categoryItem'][0]['virtuemart_category_id'],
                'category_name' => $item['customfields'][0]->custom_title,
                'link' => $item['link']
                
              ];

            
            $output[] = $objekt;
        }
```

Comment: Please join [joomla.se] Stack Exchange and ask all of your Joomla questions there.

Comment: Thanks, I did not know about joomla exchange. I've managed to make it myself.

Comment: If you have managed to resolve this issue on your own, please ask your same question on JSE, tick the box that says that you want to answer your own question, then post an educational answer.  After a short time, you will be able to put the green tick on your own answer to mark the page resolved.  All of these actions are important to helping future Joomla/virtuemart researchers.